# What should Linux/Unix 'make install' consist of?

Tags: linux, unix, installation, makefile

I've written a C++ program (command line, portable code) and I'm trying to release a Linux version at the same time as the Windows version. I've written a makefile as follows:

```
ayane: *.cpp *.h
    g++ -Wno-write-strings -oayane *.cpp
```

Straightforward enough so far; but I'm given to understand it's customary to have a second step, make install. So when I put the install: target in the makefile... what command should be associated with it? (If possible I'd prefer it to work on all Unix systems as well as Linux.)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

### Installation

A less trivial installer will copy several things into place, first insuring that the appropriate paths exists (using `mkdir -p` or similar). Typically something like this:

- the executable goes in `$INSTALL_PATH/bin`
- any libraries built for external consumption go in `$INSTALL_PATH/lib` or `$INSTALL_PATH/lib/yourappname`
- man pages go in `$INSTALL_PATH/share/man/man1` and possibly other sections if appropriate
- other docs go in `$INSTALL_PATH/share/yourappname`
- default configuration files go in `$INSTALL_PATH/etc/yourappname`
- headers for other to link against go in `$INSTALL_PATH/include/yourappname`

### Installation path

The `INSTALL_PATH` is an input to the build system, and usually defaults to `/usr/local`. This gives your user the flexibility to install under their $HOME without needing elevated permission.

In the simplest case just use

```
INSTALL_PATH?=/usr/local
```

at the top of the makefile. Then the user can override it by setting an environment variable in their shell.

### Deinstallation

You also occasionally see `make install`s that build a manifest to help with de-installation. The manifest can even be written as a script to do the work.

Another approach is just to have a `make uninstall` that looks for the things `make install` places, and removes them if they exist.

Comment: It's also important that 'make install' should be the only step that requires root permission.

Comment: A (not very well respected convention) is to use DESTDIR as the name of the staging directory, and install in $(DESTDIR)$(prefix), where prefix is defined during the configuration and DESTDIR is set when make is run (often left empty).

Comment: Thanks dmckee. Do you have a link where this conventions are stated officially, if there is a thing like this. How would you install kernel modules?

Comment: @kuga https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard encodes decades of conventions and best practices for what goes where on a unix box. The installation of kernel modules is a very different thing from installing a program and its associated cruft, and I haven't a clue.

Answer (score 3):

In the simplest case you just copy the newly created executable into the `/usr/local/bin` path. Of course, it's usually more complicated than that.

Notice that most of these operations require special rights, which is why `make install` is usually invoked using `sudo`.

Comment: i dont have sudo installed, and actually, i dont compile anything outside of outside of the arch linux build system (ABS).  To install the package, you need to be root (or such privelages), so i agree

Comment: Of course, those without sudo can use "su -c". But they should use it to install sudo...

Answer (score -7):

make install is usually the step that "installs" the binary into the correct place.

For example, when compiling Vim, make install may place it in /usr/local/bin

Not all Makefiles have a make install

Comment: The OP asked about what make install should consist of, not what it is. He clearly had knowledge of what make install did, just not how to do it. Read the question before answering as if the OP is a complete beginner.