# How to install programs on Linux from a makefile?

Tags: c++, linux, bash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should Linux/Unix 'make install' consist of?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528399/what-should-linux-unix-make-install-consist-of)

I'm making a program that can be invoked from the command line, like `./prog arg1 arg2`. I was wondering, how can I make it so that I can run it from anywhere on the system? I know that I could put `prog` into `/usr/bin/`, but what if my program needs resources from its install directory (that can be wherever the user downloaded it)?

Comment: Such resources are typically put somewhere under `/usr/share`. The location of those is typically hardcoded into the program at compile time, i.e. the program is compiled for a particular install location. Same with config files, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the directory in which your program resides into the `path` environment variable or move your program into one of the directories already in `path` (usually requires superuser permission, which I gather you don't have for then you wouldn't ask this question).

to add a directory to the front of the search path and have the system refresh its database on `tcsh`, say

```
setenv "my/directory:"$PATH
rehash
```

on `bash`, I think, it's

```
PATH=/my/directory:$PATH
export PATH
```

(no need to rehash). Note that the above commands put your directory at the top of the search path, i.e. these will be searched before any other. Thus, if your program is called "gcc", then your program will be executed rather than the GNU C compiler. Alternatively, you can add your directory to the end of the search path, in which case your program will only be picked up if no other program of the same name is found in any of the other directories in the search path.

Answer (score 1):

You probably also want to become familiar with the [Linux Filesystem Hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard): the standard definition for "what goes where".  Here's more information:

- https://superuser.com/questions/90479/what-is-the-conventional-install-location-for-applications-in-linux

Environment variables can be defined globally ("for everybody", e.g. `/etc/profile`), or locally ("per user", e.g. `~/.bashrc`).  Here's a good summary of some of your options:

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Environment_Variables

Answer (score 0):

When you execute a programme using `prog arg1 arg2`, it's thanks to your shell, which search in the $PATH environement variable for folders where programs are. (Try `env | grep PATH` to see those folder).

You need eather to add a new directory in this variable (`export PATH="/new/directory/path/:$PATH"` if under bash, `setenv PATH "/new/directory/path/:$PATH"` if with tcsh) or copy your program and all the files it need to execute in one of the PATH folder.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of dealing with this (and Makefiles have nothing to do with them)

- Your installer could just put the files where it wants them, so your program doesn't have to search -- it can use hardcoded paths. Or you could put the path to the data directory into yet another file, which would be hardcoded (like /etc/programname.config).
- You put all your stuff into one directory (often something like /opt/programname). You can hardcode that too, of course, or your program can readlink() the /proc/pid/exe file for a good chance (no guarantee, though. In particular, it works if for example a symlink is used to point from /usr/bin/programname to your /opt/programname/bin/programname or whatever, but it won't work if that's a hardlink)
  to get the path to the executable. From there you should be able to reach your data files.

If prefer the second solution, but that's just me. The first solution works well with package managers, and it's less overkill if you don't really have a lot of data files.