# Standard linux `make install` of an application, linking to correct libs

Tags: linux, installation, makefile

I am working on an application that consists of a number of binaries, scripts, and libs. Under development this far, I've built and run inside my repository:

```
myapp:
    bin/
    include/
    lib/
    scripts/
    src/
    Makefile
```

`src/` contains code for several modules, either libs or binaries. Each have their makefiles.

Running `make` from `myapp/` sets up environment variables for target install directories, then recursively runs `make install` (which uses the environment variables) for each submodule in `src/`.

This installs the binaries, includes, and libs in the relevant subdirectory of `myapp/`, since that is how the environment variables are setup.

Now I am reaching a time where I want to install system-wide, presumably in `/usr/local`. I am also interested in keeping the ability to build and install locally in `myapp/` while developing. It is convenient to be able to run the binaries in `myapp/bin/` without having to install them system wide first.

My first plan was to keep the default `make` target creating the installables (binaries, libs, includes, scripts) under `myapp`, then have a new `install` target in `myapp/Makefile` which would copy these installables in `/usr/local/` (requiring `sudo`).

My problem is that under development, the binaries need to know where the libs are. I have been linking to the libs in `myapp/lib/` with `-Wl,-rpath=/path/to/myapp/lib`. However this will not be appropriate with system installed binaries, these should refer to `/usr/local/lib/` instead.

I can see several solutions, but none very good:

- `make install` rebuilds instead of just copying, with the environment variable target directories set in `/usr/local` instead of `myapp/`. Drawback: I think this will require `sudo` for the whole rebuild process, instead of only for the install.
- remove linking with `-Wl,-rpath`, and instead set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to include `myapp/lib` while in development, but not otherwise. Apparently this is [considered harmful](http://linuxmafia.com/faq/Admin/ld-lib-path.html). I could easily forget to unset it when I want to run system wide, and the local libs would wrongly be used.
- remove linking with `-Wl,-rpath`, and require to install the libs system wide before building the binaries locally in `myapp/`. This is cumbersome, I would like to keep the ability to clone my repo and build locally in one step.

Others have probably had this very problem, and I would like to know if there is a standard solution.

[This was interesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528399/what-should-linux-unix-make-install-consist-of), but does not deal with my issue of linking libs.

Comment: The `$ORIGIN` rpath value might be of use here. See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html . That being said I don't think `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is that bad of an idea but I would suggest wrapping it in a script for dev use (possibly even a make target that does it). I believe the autotools do that wrapping script thing for in-tree running.

Comment: Why not just create another make target like ```dev``` that'll perform the build with local ```-rpath``` while the default make builds for deployment?

Comment: @EtanReisner : `$ORIGIN` sounds interesting! It should work even if installed in `/usr/local/*`. I'm reconsidering `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but I'm afraid that I'd often scratch my head trying to figure why my change in a library doesn't seem to have any effect, only to find out that I'm not using the right one. How could a make target set it? It would only be set for this `make` process, possibly for the children if I `export` it, but not for the calling shell.

Comment: @dekkard : that's a possibility. But then I need to rebuild all the libs and binaries for `install`, instead of just building once then install *exactly* what I have been testing locally.

Comment: The make target idea was a `rundev` (or similar) target which just sets things up/runs the script that sets things up for the dev usage with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. And yes, the idea of `$ORIGIN` is that the binaries/libraries are relocatable as a unit.

Comment: @EtanReisner : but again, setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in a `make` process would have no effect when the processes finishes. Like running a script instead of sourcing it...

Comment: It only needs to be in effect for that script if that script runs the binary that needs it. Instead of running `./bin/yourapp` you would run `make rundev` or `./rundevbin.sh` and that target/script would run the binary for testing.